# I have generated the APK file for android of my project in react native, but when I open the APK file in my phone it immediately closed

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I have generated the APK file of my project in react native, but when I open the APK file in my phone it immediately closed, after showing white screen for few seconds. I have spend a lot of time on it but cannot figure out something. need help anyone knows why it can happen

Comment: My project is running fine on phone when connected through cable but when i generate apk file. Its get close after 2 seconds

Comment: It looks like you haven‘t generated a main.js bundle.

But to give you more accurate help I‘ll need the logcat.

Comment: how you generate the apk?

Comment: One does not usually open an .apk file. But starts the application once the app is installed.

Comment: @MichaelBahl how i can show the logcat of apk that is being installed in mobile app

Comment: @chengsam from android studion and react native both but both apk have same issue

Comment: @MichaelBahl yes I  think my doesn't have main.js file i cannot find  it

Comment: That is what I am expecting…
Did you generate index.android.bundle ?

Command may differ depending on your project structure?

`npx react-native bundle --reset-cache --platform android --dev false --entry-file ./artifacts/app/index.js --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res/`

Comment: @MichaelBahl no i have not generated index.android.bundle  but before this project i have not generated any this file not index.android.bundle not main.js but still every project apk is working fine....

Comment: my react native version is new it only contain index.js and app.js and The file name has changed from index.android.js to index.js in new version

Comment: @MichaelBahl after adding index.android.bundle I'm getting duplicated resources error on android studion while gernerating apk

Comment: Can‘t help without project setup insights sorry.

Comment: @MichaelBahl i have created the index.android.bundle but still apk is not working